# DOM Based Cross-site Scripting example: Java Script does not get executed

Tags: javascript, dom, xss

I have recently read the following article about a DOM-based XSS:

https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/dom-based-cross-site-scripting-vulnerability/

But the examples provided in the article are not working as described. I created the HTML example file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
```

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script>
            document.write("<b>Current URL</b> : " + document.baseURI);
        </script>
        <h1> Welcome on my Example Page </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have put the above file in an application folder of a Web-Application deployed on the JBoss server and I have called the resource from my browser ( I have tried both IE 11 and Firefox).  IE 11 shows the resulting HTML content like this:

Current URL : undefined 
Welcome on my Example Page

while Firefox shows the resulting HTML content like this:

Current URL : https://localhost:8443/ukvlei/example.html
Welcome on my Example Page

In both cases, I can not force any of the browsers to execute the java script function after the # sign, as described in the article. When I type

```
https://localhost:8443/ukvlei/example.html#<script>alert(1)</script>
```

in the address bar of the browser, I  get the following HTML content:

under IE 11:

Current URL : undefined 
Welcome on my Example Page

under Firefox:

Current URL : https://localhost:8443/ukvlei/example.html#%3Cscript%3Ealert(1)%3C/script%3E
Welcome on my Example Page

What am I doing wrong, so that I cannot execute the java script in any of the browsers?

Thank you!

Comment: Try using [window.location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location#Browser_compatibility) as [document.baseURI](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_baseuri.asp) is not supported in ie

Comment: @scagood, thank you, that solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't run the URI through [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) so that the URI syntax is converted back to text.

Comment: that simply means that the article provided a bad example, doesn't it?

Comment: @AlexMi — More likely an out-of-date one. It was published three and a half years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank both @scagood and @Quentin, with whose help I got my question answered. So, the answer is:

1.) Apperantly the provided example in the article is out of date, as it is around three years old, so:
2.) Use window.location.href instead of document.baseURI;
3.) To make the example run both under IE and Firefox, decode the URL using decodeURIComponent.

So, the working example HTML file now looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script>
            document.write("<b>Current URL</b> : " + decodeURIComponent(window.location.href));
        </script>
        <h1> Welcome on my Example Page </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```